# multiOTP ask 2FA when I try to connect foreign (remote) server with RDP

Tags: one-time-password

I installed multiOTP and the Credential Provider on a standalone Windows Server. No AD, no LDAP, etc. Just an simple standalone server.
The result as expected at first. When I try to connect THIS server via RDP, the multiOTP ask 2FA. And working...

But the problem:
When I start RDP client (mstsc.exe) on THIS server, and try to connect to ANY foreign/other server, multiOTP always ask 2FA.

How can I disable multiOTP (or Credential Provider) to ask 2FA for foreign server connections?